# How to increase the speed of calculate string similarity score within dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, similarity

I have a dataframe as follow:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 'Berlin',], [2, 'Paris', ],
                    [3, 'Lausanne', ], [4, 'Bayswater',],
                    [5, 'Table Bay', ], [6, 'Bejing',],
                    [7, 'Bombay',], [8, 'About the IIS']],
                    columns=['id', 'text'],)
```

and I want to use jaro_winkler from library jellyfish to calculate the similarity score for each string compare with the all of rest, and out put the most similarity one or got the similarity score matrix as follow:

```
      str1 str2 str3
str1    1   0.6  0.7
str2    0.6  1   0.3
str3    0.7  0.3  1
```

how I can get this result as the fast way. Now I just using loop to comparison each one and store the result in list.

```
 def sim_cal(string1, string2):
     similar = jellyfish.jaro_winkler(string1, string2)
     return similar
```

But if the data become large the speed will very slow, so if have any way can speed up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With [Gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) you can do things like [this](https://www.kaggle.com/kwisatzhaderach/extended-examples-of-glove2word2vec-in-kernels).

I used [GloVe](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) for this timed example:

[image]

Not gonna lie, it's pretty entertaining.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it`s not influenced  by the way calculate the similarity score, I use my way what I post also the time consuming for each pair of strings similar as your`s.